Husky commit-message hook not triggering
I'm trying to use commitlint lint commit messages against the Conventional Commit standard. Here is my relatively basic commitlint.config.js file:
export default {
  extends: ["@commitlint/config-conventional"]
};


When linting through the cli I get the errors I would expect.
git commit -m "This isn't a good commit message" > error ❌
git commit -m "chore(deps)!: upgrade something" > works ✅
However, when using Husky my pre-commit hooks work but not my commit message hooks. Here is my commit-msg file:
pnpx commitlint $1

However, refering back to the above example the results are as follows:
git commit -m "This isn't a good commit message" > works ✅
git commit -m "chore(deps)!: upgrade something" > works ✅
Meaning commitlint isn't working. Why isn't it triggering. I'm getting no errors.

Does the pnpx commitlint $1 command have any output? If so, can you share it? Also, what is the status code of that command?

Removing node_modules and running pnpm install. Fixed the issue. It seems I was using deprecated code.
